Abuse of Leibniz notation on differential n-forms
Leibniz notation is notorious for being abused.
e.g.
Chain rule: $$\frac{dy}{dt}= \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}$$
Inverse Function Theorem: $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \left(\frac{dx}{dy}\right)^{-1}$$
Separation of Variables: $$f(y)\frac{dy}{dx}=g(x) \implies f(y) dy = g(x) dx$$
and in particular, it is very useful for dealing with (total) differential of a scalar function, or equivalently, exterior derivative of 0-forms.
e.g.
Let $f(x,y)$ be a function of 2 variables,
Then $$df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy$$
Now we can "divide" both sides by $dx$ to get
$$\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{dx}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$$
Which shows that the total derivative = partial derivative for a function with such simple dependence.
and if we want to take a derivative with respect to some parametrized curve $(x(t),y(t))$,
then we can "divide" both sides by $dt$ to get
$$\frac{df}{dt}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dt}$$
Then "multiply" both sides by $dt$ without cancellation  to get
$$df=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dt}\right)dt$$
Which is the parametrized form for the gradient theorem.
So, exterior derivative of 0-form and the total derivative is very compatible via abuse of Leibniz notation.
Now my question is
Is there a way to abuse the Leibniz notation in a meaningful way for differential $k$-form for $k > 1$? Say is there a way to work out relationship between area integrals and its rate of change with respect to some quantity (e.g. likes of Green's Theorem) via abuse of notation? Or is this a special quirk of relationship between 0-form and 1-form?
EDIT:
The notion that is more compatible with Leibniz abuse of notation for higher order derivative is called higher order differential as outlined in this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function
This is compatible with abuse of notation of higher order derivatives, but not so much with multiple integrals.

You can deduce Jacobian determinants like this.
